# date format issuse in vue2-datepicker

Tags: datepicker, vuejs2

I am using "vue2-datepicker" plugin in my vuejs2 project. "yyyy MM dd" is the default format in that datpicker but I want the change format like "dd MMM yyyy"(16-May-2016). I have changed the format in my script but it's not reflecting in the UI. It shows "16-05-2018" as the output.

```
<template>
 <b-card>
   <div>
    <date-picker v-model="dob" :lang="lang" :format="format"></date-picker>
   </div>
 </b-card>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker'

eexport default {
  name: 'addEmpl',
   components: {
    DatePicker 
  },
  data () {
    return {
      dob: '',
      lang:{
        default : 'en'
      },
      format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've created a feature request for this ~ https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/100

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the author of vue2-datepicker has implemented month names, even though they're included in [some i18n files](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/blob/master/datepicker/languages.js).

There's a PR open for improving the documentation ~ https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/pull/95

You'll have to implement a custom formatter. For example (using the provided `translation` computed property in the `DatePicker` component)...

```js
Vue.use(DatePicker.default); // don't worry about this, it's just for the demo

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dob: '',
    lang: 'en' // this sets the language object to use
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate (d) {
      // you could also provide your own month names array
      const months = this.$refs.datePicker.translation.months
      return `${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, 0)} ${months[d.getMonth()]} ${d.getFullYear()}`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-datepicker@1.9.7/dist/build.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <date-picker ref="datePicker" v-model="dob" :lang="lang" :custom-formatter="formatDate"></date-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: Please guide, how to generate this link https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-datepicker@1.9.7/dist/build.min.js with the latest version because there is newer versions available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for, How to change date format in vue2 date picker

`:format="'DD-MM-YYYY'"`

```
<date-picker
  prefix-class="xmx"
  v-model="form.dateSelector"
  id="date-selector"
  ref="date_selector"
  :disabled-date="(date) => date < new Date()"
  :format="'DD-MM-YYYY'"
  placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
  type="date"
  required
></date-picker>
```